# /main.dart: Error: Error when reading '/main.dart': The system cannot find the file specified. error on anotherone

Tags: flutter, build, apk, flutter-dependencies

When I perform a flutter build apk I get an error

/main.dart: Error: Error when reading '/main.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

package:bscsb//main.dart: Error: No 'main' method found.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
  o exit value 1
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s

Why is this happening and how can I fix this ?

build apk successfully

Answer (score 0):

As stated `Error: No 'main' methodfound. Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.`
You should create a File named main.dart (under lib/) and add a function called main.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
   const MyApp(),
  );
}
```

See this docs for more details:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/runApp.html